# Can't Xcode7.1 code sign with certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

When I run my project with device in Xcode 7 & 7.1. There is a dialog tips to input the private key password,after that, another dialog tips code sign confirm like this page [image].

**The Problem is** the buttons in this dialog don't work except for "Refuse". In that I can't run my project on my device.

Is that a bug of Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

You can try as follow steps.

1. Open the "钥匙串访问"
2. Find the "privateKey"
3. Right Click the key
4. Open the "访问控制"
5. "允许所有应用程序访问此项目"